# jQuery and usercontrols not always connecting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, vb.net-2010

I have a asp.net-page that has 3 usercontrols.
The 3 usercontrols have a jQueryUI-datepicker.

When my page is loaded, 1 of the controls is visible, the other 2 are not.

When I select in a dropdown a different value, the corresponding usercontrol is displayed.

The problem is that my datepicker isn't working correctly.

The code for the datepicker :

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtCiStartDateF").datepicker();
    $(".needs-bdatepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        altFormat: 'yy-M-dd',
        minDate: '+5d'
    });
});

<tr runat="server">
    <td><asp:Label ID="FromDateLabel" runat="server">From date:</asp:Label></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtCiStartDateF" runat="server" class="needs-bdatepicker"/>
        <asp:TextBox id="txtCiStartDate" CssClass="hidden" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

The same code is on the other controls but the with a different control-id.

The code to switch between the controls :

```
Private Sub HideAllUserControls()
    ChangeFrequency.Visible = False
    ChangeOpeningHours.Visible = False
    ChangeCiNumber.Visible = False
End Sub
Protected Sub TicketSubTypeSelected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TicketSubTypeDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged
    HideAllUserControls()

    Select Case TicketSubTypeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value
        Case TicketSubType.ChangeFrequency
            TransportTypeRow.Visible = True
            ChangeFrequency.CiNumber = CINumberTextBox.Text
            ChangeFrequency.CustomerCode = CustomerCodeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text
            ChangeFrequency.Visible = True
        Case TicketSubType.ChangeOpeningHours
            TransportTypeRow.Visible = True
            ChangeOpeningHours.CiNumber = CINumberTextBox.Text
            ChangeOpeningHours.CustomerCode = CustomerCodeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text
            ChangeOpeningHours.Visible = True
        Case TicketSubType.ChangeCiNumber
            TransportTypeRow.Visible = False
            ChangeCiNumber.CiNumber = CINumberTextBox.Text
            ChangeCiNumber.CustomerCode = CustomerCodeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text
            ChangeCiNumber.Visible = True
        Case Else

    End Select
End Sub
```

When I'm clicking the textbox the datepicker isn't displaying.
When i click the textbox before I've selected a different value from the dropdown, the datepicker opens just fine.
When I select a different value from the dropdown, i'm not getting the datepicker.

Update: when I first come on the page, the datepicker works fine. I noticed that my control has the class "hasDatepicker". When I select a different value from the dropdown, the control doens't have the "hasDatepicker"-class anymore.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please either share a working example (prob easiest 'save page as' then share in jsfiddle or other sharing method, not post all here) so we can run it, or at least more context on "isnt working correctly". That code you shared cant help us much and also doesnt include that switching code, which may be causing this. Are ANY datepickers working? is there anything in the console logs?

Comment: Added some additional explications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.
In every usercontrol I repeated the code to set my datepicker.
I've moved that from my usercontrols to the containing page.
And now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `.datepicker()` twice on the same element. The second textbox isn't even a datepicker according to your code.

Add `$("[id=$txtCiStartDate]").datepicker()`

Answer (score 0):

Your control is probably nested inside another container control. In such cases the ID rendered on the page (i.e. `ClientId` property on server side) may not be the same as the server-side control ID. The container control ID will be concatenated with it.

So do not rely on the control ID in your JavaScript code. Use ways to get the reference of that control by other means.

Since you are using jQuery, one way would be to look at the end of ID. e.g. like this `$("input[id$=txtCiStartDateF]")`. This would select all the controls that have ID ending with txtCiStartDateF, and would be basically the control of your interest.

There are other ways too to select the control, but I hope you got the point.